# If elseif with variable for numeric calculations

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two textbox to enter digits and doing sum of those numbers using javascript.

I have below condition to display results

1. If textbox 1 (id : left) is undefined or value is 0 =  do not display any output
2. If  textbox 1 (id : left) has a value, check value of textbox 2 (id : right)
3. If textbox 2 (id : right) is undefined or value is 0 =  do not display any output
4. If textbox 2 (id : right)  has a value other than undefined\ 0, check value of textbox 1 (id : left) and if textbox 1 has a value other than undefined\ 0, display result
5. If textbox 2 (id : right)  has a value other than undefined\ 0, check value of textbox 1 (id : left) and if textbox 1 is  undefined\ 0, display : please enter value in "textbox 1"

I am trying to achieve this using javascript if, elseif statement but unsuccessful

Here is the fiddle setup :http://fiddle.jshell.net/gYV8Z/6/  Am I doing correct here ?

Comment: You have a jQuery tag on the question but no jQuery in the code. Do you want a jQuery answer or plain code?

Comment: The fiddle that was set-up is not having any jQuery usage. Hence I am assuming @acr is looking for plain javascript code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
window.onload = function () {

    var left = document.getElementById('left'),
        right = document.getElementById('right'),
        result = document.getElementById("result");
    //  encase the logic inside the function
    function check(a, b, elem) {
        // No need to check for undefined as you using parseFlaot
        // So you are setting it to zero before passing the values
        // Just pass them to this function
        var txt = '';
        if (a === 0 || b === 0) {
           txt = "Please enter values into the input"
        } 
        else {
            txt = a + b;
        }
        result.innerHTML = txt;
    }

    left.onkeyup = calc;
    right.onkeyup = calc;

    function calc() {
        var a = parseFloat(left.value) || 0;

        var b = parseFloat(right.value) || 0;
        // Call the method where logic implemented 
        // You need to call it whenever the event is triggered
        check(a,b, this);
    }
}
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/gYV8Z/9/)**

Comment: It satisfying 1,2 and 3rd condition but not 4 and 5.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the javascript code

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="input-left"><span><input onblur="calc()"  class="textbox" id="left" name="count" type="text" size="5"  value="" /></span>
</div>
<div class="input-right"><span><input onblur="calc();"  class="textbox" id="right" name="count" type="text" size="5"  value="" /></span>
</div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function calc() {
    var a = parseFloat(document.getElementById('left').value) || 0;
    var b = parseFloat(document.getElementById('right').value) || 0;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = (a + b) || "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the 'IF' 'ELSE IF' statements without function/operation calls to run when the tests have passed.  You could clean the whole thing up by simply including the tests within your 'calc()' function.

Like so:

```
window.onload = function(){

var left = document.getElementById('left');
var right = document.getElementById('right');
var result = document.getElementById("result");

function calc() {
if ((left.value != undefined) || (right.value != undefined)) {
    var a = parseFloat(left.value) || 0;
    var b = parseFloat(right.value) || 0;
    result.innerHTML = ( a + b ) || "";
} else {
     result.innerHTML = "Enter appropriate values";
}
}

left.onkeyup = calc;
right.onkeyup = calc;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gYV8Z/6/embedded/result/